# problem with loop -JS

Tags: javascript, loops, dojo, for-loop

i have many pieces of code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.query("body").delegate("#input0 > select.estatistica", "onchange", function(evt){
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "drop2.php",
            handleAs: "json",
            postData: "data=" + $(this).val(),
            preventCache: true,
            load: function(json) {
                $m0 = [];

                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    $m0.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                }
                dojo.addOnLoad(refreshChar0);

            }
        });
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.query("body").delegate("#input1 > select.estatistica", "onchange", function(evt){
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "drop2.php",
            handleAs: "json",
            postData: "data=" + $(this).val(),
            preventCache: true,
            load: function(json) {
                $m1 = [];

                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    $m1.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                }
                dojo.addOnLoad(refreshChart1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

i tried this loop, but i am not sure about the script. Probably i have syntax errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for(x=0; x<10; x++) {
dojo.query("body").delegate("'#input'+x+'> select.estatistica'", "onchange", function(evt) {
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "drop2.php",
            handleAs: "json",
            postData: "data=" + $(this).val(),
            preventCache: true,
            load: function(json) {
                $m+x = [];

                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    $m+x.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                }
                dojo.addOnLoad(refreshChart+x);
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: i don't think `$m+x` is a valid variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create a variable name dynamicaly you have to use bracket notation

e.g: `this['$m'+x]` or `window['$m'+x]` will create a variable called `$m1` where `x = 1`

try:

```
window['foo' + 'bar'] = 'hello';
alert(foobar);
```

Comment: by steps. this is correct? .delegate("'#input'+x+'> select.estatistica'",

Comment: or better yet give those inputs a class and use `.delegate("input.someclassname > select.estatistica",....`

Comment: i tried with your solution, but now i get a new error.TypeError: mll[x] is not a function. I don't know, but i think that is a dojo error. If you have interest you can check here http://dojotoolkit.org/community/

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of `$m+x` I'm guessing that you're trying to create a variable dynamically such as `$m0` to `$m9` based on iterating from 0 - 10. You can't do that in Javascript as far as I'm aware it will give you an error. I suggest instead of creating a dynamic variable sort of thing why not fill the values inside an array based on the indexes of `x`.

Here's something:

```
var $m = [];
for(x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    // some of your codes here ... 

    // make $m[x] an array
    if (typeof $m[x] == "undefined")
        $m[x] = [];

    // some of your codes here...

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // of course you need to change this to what you need to push
        $m[x].push(i);
    }

}

console.log($m[0]); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So basically `$m` will be an array with arrays. I don't know if my guess is right but I hope it gives an idea.